# Why [nev] and [userid] does not receive the value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to give the variable a value but it doesn't work for some reason, I want to read from Firestore one document which has auto generated id.

[image]

thanks for help!

Comment: Please post your code as text (and not image) so we can copy it and test it easily. Also what is not working? You need to pass userUID in `.whereEqualTo()` instead of the whole  Firebase Auth instance (mAuth)

Comment: Have you tried to check if something happens if the task is not successful?